# Use gulp task to change urls in css file

Tags: javascript, gulp

Hi I am writing a gulp task to change the original urls in my fonts.css file. 
The urls need to change to point to another path once fractal (styleguide) is built.

The current urls in the file look like this `url('/assets/fonts/font.ttf');`

I want my gulp task to look in the file `fonts.css`

and replace all the url to look like `url(./font.ttf);`

here is the task

```
var config = require('../config');
if (!config.tasks.js) return;

var gulp = require('gulp');
var replace = require('gulp-replace');

var fontURL = function () {
    return gulp.src('../site/fractal/components/preview/fonts.css')
    .pipe(replace('url("/assets/fonts/', 'url("./'))
}

gulp.task('font:url', ['fractal'], fontURL);
module.exports = fontURL
```

I am incorporating this task along with several others in the fractal:build task so that when someone runs that command to power up the styleguide this is taken care of dynamically instead of one having to change many paths/urls. However this task is not working. Is there another way to accomplish what I want?

A snippit of the fonts.css file and an example of all the css urls I want to change (there are many more)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Overpass';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Overpass Regular'), local('Overpass-Regular'), url('/assets/fonts/overpass-bold-webfont.eot');
  src: local('Overpass Regular'), local('Overpass-Regular'), url('/assets/fonts/overpass-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       local('Overpass Regular'), local('Overpass-Regular'), url('/assets/fonts/overpass-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       local('Overpass Regular'), local('Overpass-Regular'), url('/assets/fonts/overpass-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       local('Overpass Regular'), local('Overpass-Regular'), url('/assets/fonts/overpass-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
       local('Overpass Regular'), local('Overpass-Regular'), url('/assets/fonts/overpass-regular-webfont.svg#overpass') format('svg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick question: do you save the modified files at some point?  Your fontURL() has no gulp.dest.

Also, I would simplify this

```
.pipe(replace('url("/assets/fonts/', 'url("./'))
```

Change that to :

```
.pipe(replace( '/assets/fonts/', './') )
```

Comment: the process goes like this in the fractal build

1 there is a task for generating all these files into their production ready directories

2 I have a task to copy all the files fractal needs to build the styleguide and I move them into the fractal dir

3 for the fonts.css in the fractal dir  is where I want to run this task . . .should I dest into the same folder?

I'll update the question with a sample of the fonts css file and all the urls I'm trying to mod